# SEVERE: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Netty

Tags: netty

I have created some game server, and I just tested it with around 10 mates. Everything went smooth, we played around 10 minutes, and at some point of the game, the game server stopped serving clients, disconnected everyone, and also my SSH that was connected to the VPS that runs the game disconnected aswell (I am not sure why) but before the disconnection I always get this message:

```
Sep 20, 2017 5:14:11 PM io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector reportUntracedLeak
SEVERE: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel() See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
```

I need to debug and know what does this message really mean, what is the direction of this bug.

I don't really know what part of my code needed to figure it out.

```
private void decodeData(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buffer, List<Object> out) {
    if (buffer.readableBytes() >= length) {
        ByteBuf data = buffer.readBytes(length);
        out.add(new Packet(opcode, data));
        setState(PacketDecodeState.OPCODE);
    }
}
```

After I finish reading the data, I do not call `buffer.release()` because then it won't really process any packets, just a wrong behavior and Im sure it is wrong to put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `Packet` holds a reference to a new created `ByteBuf` you need to ensure you call `ByteBuf.release()` of this `ByteBuf` otherwise you create a memory leak.